# iOS not reporting disk space correctly

Tags: ios, bug, disk-space

My iPhone claims I have no disk space left on the device. This is simply not true. Rebooting the phone did not help. Is there anything else I can do?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your screenshots say that you have almost ran out of free space. This make your phone tell you you're out of free space. It's not a 100% exact message, it's a message you get when you have used ~99% of your space. This is correct behaviour.

Comment: Right, following 0% free disk space, i did delete an app to get at least something. I believe that iOS is underreporting. Following the list of apps and simple counting of top 5, I am nowhere near being near 15g

Comment: Well, the sum of what is listed does not equal the 'used space' entry at the top. This is normal as some data might not be categorisable or might not be app data but different user data. In some cases connecting to iTunes gives you a better overview as it does a different space calculation. If you want to be sure, wipe and do a clean install (after a back-up of course!). Categorised space counters are inherently inaccurate.

Comment: Hmm ... Interesting. I'll try the iTunes route. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I lost about 700mb disk space when I tried (unsuccessful) to open a movie in another app. I removed both apps but I still don't get that disc space back. I tried restarting iPhone but that also didn't help.